# How to read connection string from appsettings.json in a DBContext file in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have defined a connection string in the appsettings.json file. now I want to read it in my TextDBConext file, how can I do it?

```
public class TestContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<TestTable> TestTable { get; set; }
        public TestContext()
        {
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Connection string"); //I have hardcoded here, but I want from appsettings.json
        }
    }
```

**Appsettings.json file:**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "connection_string": "Connection String"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get ConnectionString from appsettings.json instead of being hardcoded in .NET Core 2.0 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796776/get-connectionstring-from-appsettings-json-instead-of-being-hardcoded-in-net-co)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566872/create-3-tier-architecture-in-dotnet-core-2-2-web-api-c-sharp/55567348#55567348 check section set connection string

Comment: Have a look [read connectionstring outside startup from appsetting.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34269106/read-connectionstring-outside-startup-from-appsetting-json-in-vnext)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can setup your db context in the startup file and not override `OnConfiguring` at all. 
Just add a constructor that takes `DbContextOptions<TContext>` to your DbContext class. This constructor should pass on the parameter to the `base` class' constructor,
then call `AddDbContext<TContext>` in your `Startup.Configure` as follows:

```
// your TestContext showing constructor
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext(DbContextOptions<TestContext> options) : base(options){ }
}

// Then in Startup.cs
public class Startup
{
   public IConfiguration Configuration {get;}

   public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
      Configuration = configuration;
   }

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddDbContext<TeamsDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("connection_string")));
   }
}
```

Worth noting is that the `AddDbContext<TContext>` method has overloads that allow setting the service lifetime for the context to Singleton or Transient if you so wish. The default is Scoped.

Comment: Documented by Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#constructor-argument

Answer (score 3):

You can inject `IConfiguration` into `TestContext` constructor and then use `GetConnectionString(string name)` method to get the connection string.

So..

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public TestContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("Your Connection String Name"));
    }
}
```

Comment: but how to pass configuration in the TestContext constructor while initializing?

Comment: This is the job of the dependency injection system that you should have setup in your Startup.cs file

Comment: @Steve unfortunately, my _configuration object returns null even though I am calling AddSingleton(Configuration) in Startup.cs. Any idea?